# Scala Source.fromInputStream not generating full results

Tags: python, scala, rest

We are working on writing an existing python utility into Scala. Utility downloads compressed data from a REST API as ".gzip" file.

Python code :

```
response=requests.get(url,stream=True,headers=self.header,proxies=config.PROXIES,timeout=config.TIMEOUT)
        with open(file_path, 'wb+') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, f)
```

While in scala I am writing it this way :

```
var out: GZIPOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile))
    var writer= new PrintWriter(out)
    try {
      val inputStrem: InputStream = response.getEntity.getContent
      val gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(inputStrem)
      for(line <- Source.fromInputStream(gzipInputStream).getLines){
        writer.write(line+"\n")
      }          
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => throw e
     }finally {
      if (writer != null) writer.close
    }
```

But the output file is getting produced of different sizes every time with scala code. Python code is running fine. 
REST POST and GET requests are same for both utilities. 
I am not getting any errors in scala , its getting executed successfully but creating different sizes files. 
Any help would be really appreciated .

Thank You !!

Comment: Is the output different each time you execute the code, or just different from the python code?

Comment: I think the `line +"\n"` is messing up your file, I would try to get each byte from the `InputStream` individually and pass it to the writer.

Comment: Why are you decompressing and re-compressing the data?

Comment: You can omit the `catch` block, it isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is Apache HTTP then `HttpEntity` has a `writeTo` method that writes the content directly to an `OutputStream`.

```
response.getEntity().writeTo(new FileOutputStream(outputFile))
```

This does not re-encode the data like the original Scala does, but the Python version does not do that either.